# How to delete the first column ( which is in fact row names) from a data file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have data file with many thousands columns and rows. I want to delete the first column which is in fact the row counter. I used this command in linux:

```
cut -d " " -f 2- input.txt > output.txt
```

but nothing changed in my output. Does anybody knows why it does not work and what should I do?

This is what my input file looks like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 ...
     1 0 0 0 1
     2 0 1 0 1
     3 0 1 0 0
     4 0 0 0 0 
     5 0 1 1 1 
     6 1 1 1 0
     7 1 0 0 0 
     8 0 0 0 0
     9 1 0 0 0
     10 1 1 1 1
     11 0 0 0 1
    .
    .
    .
```

I want my output look like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 ...
0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
.
.
.
```

I also tried the `sed` command:

```
 sed '1d' input.file > output.file
```

But it deletes the first row not the first column.

Could anybody guide me?

Comment: your cut command works on my laptop on ubuntu with bash.

Comment: The command doesn't change anything in the input, it should create the output file different to the input, though.

Comment: I suppose that your columns are not separated by a space.

Comment: @Cyrus I checked my input file. they are separated by space but I do not understand why there is several spaces before reaching to the first column in my input file. Could this be an issue and if yes  can I delete them?, I edited my post to show you how my real input looks like.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@Karafka I had CSV files so I added the "," separator (you can replace with yours

```
cut -d"," -f2- input.csv  > output.csv
```

Then, I used a loop to go over all files inside the directory

```
# files are in the directory tmp/
for f in tmp/*
do
    name=`basename $f`
    echo "processing file : $name"
    #kepp all column excep the first one of each csv file 

    cut -d"," -f2- $f > new/$name
    #files using the same names are stored in directory new/  
done
```

Comment: why do you think the delimiter is a comma?  Neither the input/output samples, nor description/scripts mention it.

Comment: It could be anything instead of a coma, for instance, in your example you have a space " " as a separator. You can replace the "," with " ".

Comment: Yes it could be comma, but it's not.  Also there is a singe input/output file.  It's probably the right answer for another question but I'm at a loss to understand why this is the selected answer for *this* question?

Answer (score 48):

idiomatic use of cut will be

```
cut -f2- input > output
```

if you delimiter is tab ("\t").

Or, simply with `awk` magic (will work for both space and tab delimiter)

```
 awk '{$1=""}1' input | awk '{$1=$1}1' > output
```

first awk will delete field 1, but leaves a delimiter, second awk removes the delimiter.  Default output delimiter will be space, if you want to change to tab, add `-vOFS="\t"` to the second awk.

UPDATED

Based on your updated input the problem is the initial spaces that cut treats as multiple columns.  One way to address is to remove them first before feeding to cut

```
sed 's/^ *//' input | cut -d" " -f2- > output
```

or use the `awk` alternative above which will work in this case as well.

Comment: @ karakfa thanks! could you recomend me a way for deleting these row counter column if there not be any deliminator between different coulmn? my mean is if my input looks like: 10001
     20101
     30100
     40000 
     50111 then how can I delete row numbers which in my real data is from 1 to 117000?

Comment: If you're sure that the row numbers start with line number awk comes to the rescue!  try `awk '{sub(NR,"")}1' input`

Answer (score 19):

You can use `cut` command with `--complement` option:

```
cut -f1 -d" " --complement input.file > output.file
```

This will output all columns except the first one.

Comment: no I tried it just now, it did not change any thing

Comment: Then double check your delimiter as Cyrus suggests. It works for me and your `cut` command also works for me.

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f2- input.file` does the same thing as `cut -f1 -d' ' --complement` without the extra typing.

Answer (score 3):

As @karakfa notes, it looks like it's the leading whitespace which is causing your issues.

Here's a `sed` oneliner to do the job (that will account for spaces or tabs):

```
sed -i.bak "s|^[ \t]\+[0-9]\+[ \t]\+||" input.txt
```

Explanation:

```
-i       edit existing file in place
.bak     backup original file and add .bak file extension (can use whatever you like)

s        substitute
|        separator (easiest character to read as sed separator IMO)
^        start match at start of the line
[ \t]    match space or tab
\+       match one or more times (escape required so sed does not interpret '+' literally)
[0-9]    match any number 0 - 9
```

As noted; the `input.txt` file will be edited in place. The original content of `input.txt` will be saved as `input.txt.bak`. Use just `-i` instead if you don't want a backup of the original file.

Also, if you know that they are definitely leading spaces (not tabs), you could shorten it to this:

```
sed -i.bak "s|^ \+[0-9]\+[ \t]\+||" input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve this with grep:

```
grep -E -o '[[:digit:]]([[:space:]][[:digit:]]){3}$' input.txt
```

Which assumes single character digit and space columns. To accommodate a variable number of spaces and digits you can do:

```
grep -E -o '[[:digit:]]+([[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+){3}$' input.txt
```

If your grep supports the `-P` flag (`--perl-regexp`) you can do:

```
grep -P -o '\d+(\s+\d+){3}$' input.txt
```

And here are a few options if you are using GNU sed:

```
sed 's/^\s\+\w\+\s\+//' input.txt
sed 's/^\s\+\S\+\s\+//' input.txt
sed 's/^\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+//' input.txt
sed 's/^\s\+[[:digit:]]\+\s\+//' input.txt
```

Note that the grep regexes are matching the parts that we want to keep while the sed regexes are matching the parts we want to remove.