# Remove text before first comma character

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm trying to use sed to remove everything before the first comma, including that comma, but retaining everything after that. I know there are simmilar questions on this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479884/remove-everything-in-a-line-before-comma) and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232657/delete-till-first-occurrence-of-colon-using-sed)), but I am being unable to modify these cases for this specific task.

Say I have a list CSV like:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

After running sed like:

```
sed 's/^.*,//' file.csv
sed 's/^.*,(.*)/(1)/' file.csv
```

In the first case I see that only the last column is retained, and with the second nothing happens. I expected however, that both cases would work similarly:

- `^`: would match the beggining of line.
- `.*`: anything, any number of times.
- `,`: I'd expect this to match **the first comma**, why not?

Comment: Try with `sed 's/^[^,]+,//' file.csv`

Comment: "Why not?"  Because `*` is greedy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812916/how-to-delete-the-first-column-which-is-in-fact-row-names-from-a-data-file-in/32814062

Comment: @ctwheels solution works If fixed to `sed 's/^[^,]*,//' file.csv`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Using back references concept of `sed` here, where matching everything till first occurrence of `,`(comma) and then keeping save everything in a temporary buffer memory which later while substituting I am using it by doing `\1`.

```
sed 's/[^,]*,\(.*\)/\1/' Input_file
```

Why OP's attempt is not working, since OP is using `.*,` and `.*` being a Greedy character it covers till last occurrence of `,` so in spite of catching very first occurrence of it we get value till last comma.